# Filtering in join query

Tags: crystal-reports

Using crystal reports version 14, MS sql server 2008

I am joining two tables and I need to filter in the join, so if a certain value exists in one of the table, I want to join to that record, if it does not exist, I want to have a null-record. I.e:

```
select * from sample left outer join test
on(sample.sample_number=test.sample_number and test.name='PREP')
```

I can run that in Sql server studio and get exactly what I want

What I can get in crystal reports is

```
select * from sample left outer join test   
on(sample.sample_number=test.sample_number) 
where test.name='PREP'
```

In the latter case, rows where test.name='PREP' does not exist will be removed and if there are samples that have no test.name='PREP', those samples will be removed.

Are there any ways I can do this in CR 14?

dummy tables:

Sample
sample_number,name
1,A
2,B
3,C

Test
sample_number,name
1,PREP
1,SOMETHING
2,SOMETHING
3,SOMETHING_ELSE
3,PREP

What I want:

1,A,1,PREP
2,B,NULL,NULL
3,C,3,PREP

(of course there are more fields in the tables and a selection of which fields, but this should illustrate what I want)

I know I can make views and query them directly in crystal, but if possible, I would avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Bah, found it:

Database expert - add table, select data source, add command. Then a custom sql can be added.

Comment: Thats one option. But when using Views, you do most of the processing even before the data gets to the report. I think it has better performance than using command in CR.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but for various reasons nothing should be done as far as possible to the database I am querying against...